# MYSQL : Scheduled Event, copying a row to another row in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

i am having some trouble using an event to run this query. What it does is copy the first row in column "killsZ" to the second row in the same column where the player UID is the same. When i run this as an sql query it gives me this, which is exactly what i want.

`BEGIN
UPDATE character_data ts, character_data tu SET tu.killsZ = ts.killsz WHERE tu.playerUID = ts.playerUID;
END`

`playerUID | killsZ             playerUID | killsZ
 30444550       10       ---->    30444550    10
 30444550       16                30444550    10
 62587693       23                62587693    23`

However, when i put this in a scheduled event to run every 2 seconds the result is

`playerUID | killsZ             playerUID | killsZ
 30444550       10       ---->    30444550    16
 30444550       16                30444550    16
 62587693       23                62587693    23`

It copies the second row to the first but not the first to the second like in the sql query.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: your playerUID is first and 2nd row  both are same?

Comment: SQL doesn't guarantee an order unless you use an ORDER BY clause, and even then order is not guaranteed for identical rows. There is no guarantee that the 'first' row will always be processed first. If you want to do this reliably you need to provide a mechanism to control the order in which rows are processed.

Comment: Yes i want it to copy the first row in column 'killsz' that is 10 to the second row in that column where the playerUID column has the same value in its column, so both are 10.

Comment: Yea, i just need it to copy the first row of a duplicate playerUID to the second. How would i order it in an event to get the same result and not the second row copied to the first

Comment: If it may help, there is also a column in this same table that has AUTO_INCREMENT where in the first row it is always a lower number than the second and so on. Maybe i could order it that way?

Comment: Solved. Thanks. UPDATE character_data tu, character_data ts SET tu.killsZ = ts.killsz WHERE tu.playerUID = ts.playerUID AND ts.characterID < tu.characterID